# Creating a case in plugin, want to use its ticketnumber immediately

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin where i am creating a new case and I want to send an email out as it is created including its ticketnumber. I have attempted just to call this in the plugin but it is coming back saying that it is not present in the dictionary. I know this field is populated using CRM's own autonumbering so what i'm guessing is happening is that my plugin is firing and creating the case but then i'm trying to use this field before the autonumber has completed.

So is there a way that i can get my plugin to "wait" until this field is available and then use it?

Thanks

EDIT: Code below:

```
string emailBody = entity.Attributes["description"].ToString();

int bodyLength = emailBody.Length;
int textStart = emailBody.IndexOf(">") + 1;

int newLength = bodyLength - (textStart + 7);

string description = emailBody.Substring(textStart, newLength);

//create complaint
Entity complaint = new Entity("incident");

complaint["description"] = description;
complaint["ts_case_type"] = 717750001;
complaint["ts_registration_datetime"] = DateTime.Now;
complaint["ownerid"] = Owner;
complaint["customerid"] = Organisation;

Service.Create(complaint);
```

Comment: What does your plugin registration/code look like?

Comment: I have added the code to the initial post. I'm taking information from an email activity and creating a case from it

Comment: How are you trying to read back the autonumber field in that code? Additionally could this just be achieved in a workflow on creation of an incident?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you just wanted my general code. I was literally just calling it like string number = complaint["ticketnumber"].toString();

I need to use it in the same code as it continues to do more things after I have created the incident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side I would suggest sending the email with a workflow if possible, it will be far easier to maintain in the long run and quicker to implement in the short.

In any case to answer your question, from what you have here you need to update your code to retrieve the ticketnumber once you have created the incident. You can do this with a [Retrieve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx) message.

For example:

```
//Create the complaint
Entity complaint = new Entity("incident");

//This is the information that is being sent to the server,
//it will not be updated by CRM with any additional information post creation
complaint["description"] = description;
complaint["ts_case_type"] = 717750001;
complaint["ts_registration_datetime"] = DateTime.Now;
complaint["ownerid"] = Owner;
complaint["customerid"] = Organisation;

//Capture the id of the complaint, we will need this in a moment
Guid complaintId = Service.Create(complaint);

//complaint["ticketnumber"] <-- The server does not populate this information in your object

//Retrieve the ticketnumber from the incident we just created            
Entity complaintRetrieved = service.Retrieve("incident", complaintId, new ColumnSet("ticketnumber"));

//Get the ticketnumber
String ticketNumber = (String)complaintRetrieved.Attributes["ticketnumber"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like James said in comment, if you just want to send email with some case properties, it is best to do that with workflow (on case create).
In your plugin, ID is generated, and you can get it with:

```
entity.Attributes["ticketnumber"]
```